# Is this server (ie Game Development) under stress (or attack)?

Tags: support

I have been seeing regular weird issues recently when visiting this particular site, including **very** poor response and my tag customizations being invisible for extended periods of time. Usually it is only this site, of the 5 or 6 Stack Exchange sites I visit regularly, that are exhibiting problems.

Some details of the problems noticed:
 - several seconds to get mouse response
 - having to type characters several times because only 1 in 3 or 4 gets recognized
 - my tag customizations are lost
 - scrolling improperly

Is this a known issue or so far un recognized. I have been seeing it for a couple of weeks, but it seems (anecdotally) to be getting more frequent.

Comment: What browser are you using? Something similar happens to me occasionally using Chrome, related to [this](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/gamedev-causing-a-memory-leak). The browser and sometimes entire computer starts to get unresponsive. If using Chrome, hit Shift+Esc. Check out how much memory your sites are using. You can also try closing the tab, then hitting Ctrl+Shift+T to reopen the closed tab. This work around solves the memory issue for me. Otherwise, please give more details as to what your setup is.

Comment: @Byte56: I am using IE10. This all sounds reasonable, except I am not experiencing any issues with SO, Board-Games, English Usage, History, Mathematics, or Physics.